# In pyQt4 what is the difference between clicked() and stateChanged() signals for QCheckBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

In my experimenting I have found that in some cases the graphical check display can be changed without `stateChanged` being sent, but `clicked` appears to always go.  What is the difference?

In particular, something like this:

```
checkBox.stateChanged.connect(func)

def func(state):
  print "Not allowed!"
  checkBox.setChecked(not bool(state))
```

Does not work with `stateChanged`.  It appears to get into `func` every other time only.  What is going on?  If I replace `stateChanged` with `clicked`, it works as expected.

Comment: If you want to prevent users changing the state, you should either disable or disconnect the button. Undermining the state by re-setting it inside the slot is just asking for trouble.

Comment: While very closely related, a QCheckBox's *check state* and *checked* are *not* the same thing. The state should only be used for tristate checks, if you only need bool values, you should not use it and opt for the basic `toggled`/`setChecked` as with all QAbstractButtons.

Comment: This was a minimal example.  In my real code, you only end up undoing the action under certain conditions.  Is toggled a signal too?  If so, how different from clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can change checkbox state programmatically. `checkbox.setChecked(True)` will emit `stateChanged` but not `clicked`

Comment: If so, I wonder why I didn't get an infinite loop in the example case?

Comment: @Mastiff that's due to various fallback systems that, coincidentally, didn't cause a recursion because it was activated by user interaction. As ekhumuro said, "resetting" the value like this is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: @Mastiff There is no infinite loop because `setChecked` doesn't do anything just returns if current value is equal to value you try to assign. It's common pattern in qt setters to check and return if new value is equal to current value, specifically to avoid infinite loops.